# What does "Community Wiki" mean?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Apologies if this is obvious, but I'm new here. I see the term "community wiki" bouncing around a lot and have no idea what it means.  Maybe my reputation is not high enough to have access to community-wiki features?

Comment: UPDATE: policy has changed since this question was last answered.
---- 1. Community wiki is [no longer available on questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183) ---- 2. Answers can be marked Community Wiki if you want them to be worked on collaboratively: useful for gathering all the little bits in one place. Everybody with 100 reputation or more can edit CW answers.

Comment: Meta.SE reference: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/168244)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Community wiki is just a way to let (almost) everyone edit questions and answers. There's a check box at the bottom of the question and answer input box to select community wiki. Currently, you don't have enough rep to edit community wiki posts, but that will change very soon. See the faq.

One other feature of community wiki is that no one gains reputation for questions or answers marked community wiki (which makes sense since multiple people can edit it).

Community wiki is especially useful when a question has no real right answers. For example, this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/which-packages-can-you-use-to-improve-the-typographic-quality) is community wiki.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I couldn't find a FAQ entry or similar **describing** what community wiki is, what happens to rep, guidelines when to use it and when not, etc.....should there not be one?

Comment: I fully agree with Yossi.

Comment: Is it ok to edit community wiki answers in a way that _changes_ the meaning, as in correcting it? As an example, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/678#678) seems really imprecise to me (not differing between hyphenation rules and orthography reforms), but an edit would be more than "clarifying". The info box on the right of the editing page, however, says "clarify meaning without changing it".

Comment: @doncherry: best to ask that as a question in meta.

Comment: @TH.: If a question I asked received an excellent answer that I'd like to reward with a belated bounty, can I still do that if the question has since been turned into a community wiki question?

Comment: @SSilk: You should ask that as a separate question. I don't know the answer to that off-hand, but I suspect the answer is no.