# Community wiki: simple and exhaustive explanation

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

In relation to a question already asked [What does "Community Wiki" mean?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/what-does-community-wiki-mean), what exactly does it mean? I, for example, have not understood why this option exists.

1. Am I already included in this community or is it a privilege that it has a certain usefulness?
2. I have seen an answer for a few minutes with the indications given in the image. Is it possible to have an animated illustration in order to better understand the question?

Comment: Perhaps read this Meta.SE reference: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/168244)

Comment: @Werner Thank you with lot of heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If I understand your word "included", you are already included in this community since your registration.

   ---

   Imagine you were the leader of a company, and proposed a rule for all staffs (including you) and let everyone improve it. (i) Over time, your employees would find some inappropriate points, and they edited them for a better rule. (ii) Your rule is not your own, now it belongs to *every*one.

   Posting a Community-Wiki post is like propose an uncompleted document, like the rule above. A reader reads it and thinks he can improve it, and he edits it. However, if that reader has under 2000 rep, his edit must be reviewed, in case the post is not a CW. That number is only 100 rep for CW posts. That is the first main difference (i) between normal posts and CW posts.

   If your post is CW, you don't own it (because almost everyone can edit it freely). You can still get badges on your post, but you won't earn a single reputation from that post. This is the second main difference (ii).

   You can see that some posts on the main site should not be a CW if we consider difference (i), like [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474868/156344). However, that answer is not mine, so I don't own it, i.e. I should not get rep on that post. That is the reason why I marked that answer as CW.

   <sup>You have 10k rep, so only difference (ii) works for you. Difference (i) is only for (thousands of) users who have between 100 and 2000 rep, not for (700) users with more than 2000 rep.</sup>

   ---

   *Example:* [A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26771/156344) is a CW question. Look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26775/156344).

   Initial:

   [image]

   User Roald added a line in Revision 3:

   [image]

   It is a small adition, but it is good for the community. That is the usefulness of CW.

   ---
2. As stated above, you can improve a CW post if you think you can improve it. If your (improve?)ment is bad, someone will re-edit the post for you.

---

**This answer is CW**

I am not good at writing. If I write a long answer, it is often (a bit or too?) confusing at some points. Thus I mark this as CW for free improvements!

---

**Reference:**

1. [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
2. [Edit community wiki privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)
3. [Create community wiki posts privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)